# How do I change the Icon of IconButton.shinyInput in R?

Tags: r, shiny, fluent-ui

I'd like my Icon to be "InfoSolid" [image]

There isn't a lot of documentation about this. Cheers!

Comment: `actionButton(inputId, label, icon = icon("infoSolid"))`?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IconButton.shinyInput("coachmark_plan_activiteit", iconProps = list("iconName" = "InfoSolid"))`